# Create custom admin bar menu items

Tags: functions, admin-bar

I am using this code to create a custom menu in the admin bar. For some reason my menu items are nested in each other instead of having the `#custom_menu` as parent. Why is this happening?

```
function custom_adminbar_menu( $meta = TRUE ) {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { return; }
        if ( !is_admin_bar_showing() ) { return; }
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id' => 'custom_menu',
        'title' => __( '<span class="lifemx ab-icon"></span>Magazine' ) )
    );

  $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'parent'    => 'custom_menu',
    'title'     => '<span class="lifemm ab-icon"></span>My posts',
    'href'  => '/wp-admin/edit.php'
   )
  );

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'parent'    => 'custom_menu',
        'title'     => '<span class="lifemm ab-icon"></span>Home Page',
        'href'  => '/lifestyle/',
        'meta'  => array( target => '_blank' ) )
    );


}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'custom_adminbar_menu', 15 );
```

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of how this is appearing for you?

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: Looking at the WordPress documentation, it looks like the `add_node()` function is the preferred way of adding WP Admin Bar items now: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_node - I'm too tired to write code now but that link might help...

Comment: I replaced add_menu with add_node but still getting same problem

Comment: I think you've got to do more than just replace the function with the new function. Read on down the docs and it shows you how to add child menu items...

Comment: I've just tried your code and it worked fine for me. (On WordPress version 4.9.4) Try specifying a unique ID for each call to the `add_menu()` function. E.g. `$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array( 'parent' => 'custom_menu', 'id' => 'custom_menu-my-posts', ... ) );`

Comment: I think it's a CSS issue, since no luck with this - must be the ab-icon declaration in the span

Comment: Yes I was correct, problem fixed